# How can I tell git to track only software-related directories, and not user-generated content?

Tags: git, content-management-system

I'm currently working on a user-generated content website. The website allows users to create boards, and each of these boards are designated a directory in the project root. Because of this, git recognizes these directories as a new file, and `git status` complains about untracked files. How can I configure git so that only my CMS is tracked, and not user generated content? Using `.gitignore` doesn't seem applicable, as that would mean I'd need to manually add up to 30 directories every time I needed to do something in git. Architectural changes would be an excellent idea, however, is there any way to avoid them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your architecture allows for the creation of folders in your root folder and you don't know the names of the folders in advance. As suggested by ~felixlinker, adding a prefix to the newly created folders allows you to use .gitignore.

Another solution is to change the architecture of your project slightly and have a single folder, `usercontent` for example, and create the new folders in their, allowing you to add a single entry in your .gitignore file to exclude anything in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You prefix user-generated directories, e. g. with `usergen_` and add the following line to your `.gitginore`:

```
/usergen_*
```